# Can I access the ocr'd text in Google Drive?

Tags: google-drive-api

According to the docs [here](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/reference/files/create) OCR is performed on .jpg, .png, .gif, or .pdf files uploaded to Google Drive. And [here](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/reference/files#resource) `indexableText` seems to point to the possibility that the OCR'd text might be accessible.

However, I can't seem to do it right - the `GET` request on the file does not show `indexableText` and there does not seem to be any help anywhere.

Any hints?

In case you want a snippet, here's what I do (perl)

```
my $ua = Mojo::UserAgent::Google->new({ token => $c->session('token') });  # set useragent
my $url = Mojo::URL->new('https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files');     
push @{$url->path}, ($id);                                                 # URL including file ID
$url->query({ fields => '*' });                                            # and query for all fields

my $tx = $ua->get($url);                                                   # send a get request 
$c->render(json => $tx->res->json);                                        # and render the response as JSON
```

The response contains nothing that looks like OCR text.

Comment: Do you have a code snippet, error logs that will allow us to replicate the issue in order for us to investigate?

Comment: I have added the code snippet

Comment: The `indexableText` field is actually something you add to help Google Drive index your document. According to the page you linked to:


> Text to be indexed for the file to improve fullText queries.
> This is limited to 128KB in length and may contain HTML elements.

Comment: I know this is an old discussion, but since I've just discovered a useful link, I feel I ought to be a good citizen and add it here. :) So here it is:

https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/ocr